# Accepted Netflix answer is incorrect

Tags: discussion, answers

IMO we should remove the accepted answer, from [How can I use Netflix on Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1488/how-can-i-use-netflix-on-ubuntu). The [2nd most-voted answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/509947/85695) is clearly more correct and supported by Google/Netflix.

Right now the only supported way to use Netflix is to use Google Chrome, as the second answer recommends. Firefox 49 (due next month) also allows for native Netflix. The accepted answer recommends a PPA and installing WINE, and the netflix-desktop package only even supports up to 15.04

Comment: We (mods) can't remove the check mark, we'd have to delete the answer. That would cost the poster ~500 rep and seems unfair given that it is, actually, a pretty good answer. Since there is a nice disclaimer stating that the newer versions can do it natively and linking to the second answer, isn't that enough? If not, I guess we could ask a new question, and then merge this one into it. That would make the checkmark disappear but would keep the answers and associated rep.

Comment: The link is non-obvious and I have to scroll through nearly a page of incorrect information just to get to the right answer, I can't really ask the OP since they haven't used the site for 3 years.

Comment: Can't moderators just edit in a special note into the question explaining what's going on ? ( Implying of course that visitors read the question text  instead of scrolling straight to the answers )

Comment: @Serg we could, but there already is one at the top of the question. Also, (and please correct me if I'm wrong, Jorge) it looks like the other answer just says "use google chrome". That would make the accepted answer correct since it lets you do it with another browser. I'm not entirely clear on why one is more correct than the other. Jorge, could you expand on your reasoning a bit?

Comment: Yes, right now the only supported way to use Netflix is to use Google Chrome, Firefox 49 (due next month) also allows for native Netflix. The accepted answer recommends a PPA and installing WINE, and the netflix-desktop package only even supports up to 15.04.

Comment: @terdon "We (mods) can't remove the check mark" why not?

Comment: @Rinzwind for the same reason you can't. Mods don't have the ability to modify accept status, just like regular users.

Comment: I believe you should be able to though so I expect you to make it happen ;-)

Comment: Would editing the answer with a BFW suffice?

Comment: IIRC the powers that be have been declining every move to display an accepted answer **not** at the top.

Comment: It doesn't help that the accepted answer is longass with tons of images

Comment: Oh, btw, related [Keeping special status for Accepted Answers without sticking them to top forever?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/268666)

Comment: The one I was actually looking for [How do we encourage edits to obsolete/out of date answers?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/261817)

Comment: I edited it somewhat, is it better now? http://askubuntu.com/posts/219068/revisions

Comment: @terdon Just FTR, posts with a score of +3 or more that are more than 60 days old don't cause rep-loss when deleted. I'm not sure when this was implemented, and I assume you know about it now, but adding a note here anyway for others reading

Answer (score 9):

I have always understood the checkmark as "this is what solved it for me". Therefore, if the OP solved their problem with that answer, it should be accepted.

There is a difference between an accepted answer and the "best" answer. Sometimes they are the same, sometimes they aren't.

By the way, the specific question asks "how" to watch Netflix on Ubuntu. There is not a single valid answer, but **that doesn't mean the accepted one is incorrect.**

Answer (score 4):

The most correct answer was being eclipsed by an incorrect answer. Now that previously incorrect answer has been updated and that kludge has been partially fixed. I say *partially fixed* because the Netflix topic has popped up again today in this question: [Netflix not working in Firefox, how to fix?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/820986/netflix-not-working-in-firefox-how-to-fix).

Comment: +1 just for `kludge` :)

Comment: Do you think they should still be merged? If so, you may want to post a new meta question about that, since the idea of merging them hasn't gotten much traction here, and because at this point considerable time has passed, so it is not obvious that the recommendation to avoid Firefox in the top-voted answer of the closed question still applies. If you posted a new meta question, it could address that too.

Comment: I no longer think that they should be merged, so I edited this answer accordingly.